# RSS Failed to Fetch Wordpress Embed Videos

Tags: wordpress, video, rss

Before I go on I'd like to clarify that I use google reader to test my site's RSS feed.

Ok, if my title doesn't explain it well enough, my wordpress is using a custom made theme that I bought from some site, they actually provide support but I haven't gotten any actual answer so far, so I hope I can get some answer here.

Basically my site's RSS feed is not fetching my videos which is embed directly to post. I have troubleshoot it by using wordpress default theme, and the embed videos get fetched just right in my google reader. So I think the problem lies in the custom theme I'm using.

But I don't know how to troubleshoot and move on from this point. Anybody has got a clue what might just be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the authors of a bought Theme should offer solutions for that.

1. Try the source view of your RSS feed and check if the videos are included. If so, maybe there is some reason why Google Reader does not fetch these.
2. Add the videos to your RSS feed. Find out, how your Theme stores the videos. Write a custom function to manipulate your RSS-feed and put it into your functions.php (be carefully with updates, afterwards).

See this discussion: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-fields-on-rss-feed-how-to

Plugin for additional RSS fields:

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/01/27/custom-fields-for-feeds-wordpress-plugin

Manipulation RSS feeds:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-content-and-completely-manipulate-your-wordpress-rss-feeds/